# Any good looking 3D Game or Techdemo that makes use of deferred rendering?

Tags: 3d, deferred-rendering

For a research work arround the topic of deferred rendering/shading I'm looking for some opensource 3D game, benchmark or Techdemo upon which I can develop my examples. Of course it would be good if the game/demo would be visually appealing and as close to modern gamegraphics as possible.

I considered Doom3, but unfortunately the released version does not use deferred rendering.

While there are opensource game-engines that support deferred rendering, it's too much work to create an actual game / content so i'm looking not just for an engine but something that already has content and looks good.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: "I'm looking for some opensource 3D game, benchmark or Techdemo upon which I can develop my examples." Hurray for both copy&paste coding *and* getting other people to Google "Deferred Rendering Demo" for you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice little demo for XNA 4.0 [here](http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2010/12/28/deferred-rendering-in-xna4-0-source-code/).

Comment: I know and use this already - but the problem is that it looks sh**. I want something that can keep up at least with game graphics from the past 3-4 years. doesn't need to be a full game or so as it's only about graphics. can be techdemo or benchmark or whatever. Just visually appealing it should be

Comment: Late, but I keep getting hits via this answer so I want to set this straight: the deferred rendering technique in that (my/Catalin's) tutorial is similar to those used in AAA-titles, you just need higher quality textures and models. Then add some nice post processing effects and something like MLAA/FXAA and you should be very close to the visual quality of recent games.

Comment: @Roy: Well said.  Too many folks think to get great visuals all you need to do is just use the latest buzzword tech.  The reality is that quality comes from hard graft building great assets and adding polish, not just chopping the graphics pipeline around and abusing shaders.